# How to determine if a document is published to a live system in imperia

Tags: perl, content-management-system, publish

I would like to use the imperia API to determine if a certain document 
was published to one of the existing target systems in imperia 9.2.3.

The documents that are not yet published (only on DEV) should not be took into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since imperia 9 you can get the information 
with `Site::MetaDir`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

BEGIN {
    unshift @INC, $0 =~ /(.*)[\\\/]/
        ? "$1/../modules/core"
        : '../modules/core';
    require Imperia::Core::ScriptEnv;
    Imperia::Core::ScriptEnv->bootstrap;
}

use strict;
use Imperia;
use Site::MetaDir;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file       = "/foo/index.html";
my $MetaDirDev = Site::MetaDir->new();
my $targets    = $MetaDirDev->getTargets();

my $metainfoDev = $MetaDirDev->getMeta($file);
print "DEV : modification_date = " . $metainfoDev->getValues('__imperia_modified') . "\n";

foreach my $target (@$targets) {
    next if $target eq 'DEV';

    my $MetaDirLive  = Site::MetaDir->new($target);
    my $metainfoLive = $MetaDirLive->getMeta($file);
    if ( defined($metainfoLive) ) {
        print "$target : modification_date = " . $metainfoDev->getValues('__imperia_modified') . "\n";
    } else {
        print "file $file is not on $target \n";
    }
}
```